Setting up a help desk system with CiviCRM
I would need to implement a helpdesk system that would gather inquiries from external users of the website. However, I do not know if I should use CiviCASES or if there could be an alternative solution (I wanted to use CiviCASES to handle the different ongoing processes of my project).
Since I am already using CiviCRM, I would like to remain in the same platform.
Here are some technical specifications:

Joomla 4.4.8
CiviCRM 5.77.1

Which path would you recommend me to follow to set up this help desk system together with my CRM installation?

Welcome to SE!  Help desk systems provide a range of features.  It might help if you describe what features you want to implement.

I tried doing this using activities, scheduled reminders and all sorts of stuff. It was just a bit clunky, and very basic. In the end I decided to go for YouTrack which is free at the level of usage I need and does heaps of stuff
